# symfony translation keys formed with variables

Tags: symfony, key, translation, twig

In a twig template is it possible to form translation key with a variable in it ?

Like

`{% trans %}detail.label.price.{{membership}}.credit{% endtrans %}`

or

`{% set str = "detail.label.price"+membership+".credit"|trans %}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
{{ ('detail.label.price.' ~ membership ~ '.credit')|trans }}
```

Comment: It works fine tanks a lot. I tried with `~` but I forgot to try encapsulating with `()`. 
Thanks again